# ggplot2 - How to boxplot two variables with different scales on same plot using a primary and secondary y-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

Datalink:

[Data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kdi5uklhylr8vei/GTAP_DistEVYield.csv?m)

Code:

```
    distevyield <- read.csv(file = "F:/Purdue University/RA_Position/PhD_ResearchandDissert/PhD_Draft/GTAP-CGE/GTAP_NewAggDatabase/NewFiles/GTAP_DistEVYield.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", na.string="NA", dec=".", strip.white=TRUE)

    str(distevyield)
    distevyield <- as.data.frame(distevyield)
    distevyield[5:6] <- sapply(distevyield[5:6],as.numeric)
    distevyield <- droplevels(distevyield)
    distevyield <- transform(distevyield,region=factor(region,levels=unique(region)))
    library(ggplot2)

    distevyield.f <- melt(subset(distevyield, region !="World"))

    Figure3 <- ggplot(data = distevyield.f, aes(factor(variable), value)) 
    Figure3 + geom_boxplot() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour = 'black', angle = 90, size = 15, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5),axis.title.x = element_blank()) + 
    theme(axis.text.y = element_text(colour = 'black', size = 15, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5), axis.title.y = element_blank()) + 
    theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 14, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5, face = 'bold')) +
    facet_wrap(~region, scales="free_y")
```

Outcome:
[image: Plot result]

Question:

My two variables plotted, yield (%change) and ev (in million US$) have different units. Is there a way to add a secondary y-axis for one of the variable so as to display each variable with a boxplot representing its original units, but within the same plot? Does this feature exist in ggplot2 to begin with?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you use `scales='free_y'` with boxplots? It make comparison fairly difficult...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With ggplot2 you can't make two y axis ([see explanation/discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/how-to-use-ggplot2-make-plot-with-2-y-axes-one-y-axis-on-the-left-and-another)).

To represent different axis values for `ev` and `yield` you have to plot them in separate plots. One way to achieve this would be to use `facet_wrap()` and combine `region` and `variable` values. With `facet_wrap()` you will get both plots together and you will be able to control number of columns to show.

```
ggplot(data = distevyield.f, aes(factor(1), value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +  facet_wrap(region~variable,scales="free",ncol=8)+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y = element_blank())
```

[image]